# How does jquery return functions like success and error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked though the jquery code, and it's not clear to me.  How do I make my own function return success or error like in the following code:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/some.xml",
      success: function()
      { /** found! **/},
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        if(xhr.status==404)
          { /** not found! **/}
      }
    });
```

Comment: So, you want to know how callbacks work?

Comment: I guess that's what I want..  Not sure, not exactly a JavaScript expert.. :P  I want to make my own function that abstracts out setting the type, header, etc..  and just returns the success or error.

Comment: Just google: Pro JavaScript Techniques, John Resig 2006. The things you wanna know are covered nicely in that book.

Comment: @Brad: If it's only for that, you should not use the `success`/`error` arguments. Return the ajax [promise](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) from your function, so that the user can hook on it with `.done()`/`.fail()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` passes in an object which has `success` and `error` properties on it that are functions. In the function it will then call either `success` or `error` depending on the result. This example might help you understand better.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/DLPPN/)

```
function ifTrue(bool, params) {
    if (bool)
        params.success();
    else
        params.error();
}

ifTrue(true, {
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});

ifTrue(false, {
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please call them *properties*, not *variables*

Answer (score 0):

For more options (success, error, state, ...), I recommend to use Deffered object.
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Example:

```
    function MyFunction(parameter){
        var def = $.Deferred();
        if(DoSomeThing()){
           def.resolve();
        }
        else{
           def.reject()
        }
        return def;
    }
```

Usage:
...

```
MyFunction(xxx).then(function(){
// Success case
})
.fail(function(){
//Fail case
});
```